# How can I verify a Mockito mock is called with a specific object state when that state is subsequently changed?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

There's a service I want to test which takes a mutable input argument, calls another service to operate on it, and then changes a value on the input argument.

```java
public class Stateful {
    private String value;
    // This class also has constructor, getter, setter, equals, and hashCode using value
}
```

```java
public class StatefulService {
    private final StatefulOperation operation;
    public StatefulService(StatefulOperation op) { this.operation = op; }

    public void execute(Stateful input) {
        operation.doOperation(input);
        input.setValue("After");
    }
}
```

I want to add a [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org) unit test to mock out the external operation and verify that the expected call is happening.  One thing that I do very much want to include in my test is that the object passed to the external service is the previous version of the object, as the external service uses that value.  It would be wrong if the mutable value were changed prior to the service call, and I want a test to ensure that the call happens correctly.

I can't just pass in the expected value to [`Mockito.verify`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify-T-), since it is only checked after the test using the already-updated value:

```java
@Test
public void operationIsCalledWithSpecificState() {
    StatefulOperation operation = mock(StatefulOperation.class);
    StatefulService statefulService = new StatefulService(operation);

    statefulService.execute(new Stateful("Input"));

    // Fails, since it compares against the current state of the argument
    verify(operation).doOperation(new Stateful("Input"));
}
```

Note that I can't really change the usage pattern, since it's a database entity type which is being mutated in a framework-specific pre-save hook.

How can I verify the state of an object passed to a mock when that object's state changes after the call?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set up the object's stubbing to do the check.  This will ensure the check occurs when method is actually called, so the actual state can be checked.

Using multiple stubs:

```java
@Test
public void operationIsCalledWithSpecificState() {
    StatefulOperation operation = mock(StatefulOperation.class);
    StatefulService statefulService = new StatefulService(operation);

    doNothing().when(operation).doOperation(new Stateful("Input"));
    doThrow(AssertionError.class).when(operation)
            .doOperation(not(eq(new Stateful("Input"))));

    statefulService.execute(new Stateful("Input"));
    Mockito.verify(operation).doOperation(any());
}
```

Using a single stub with an [`Answer`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.2/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html):

```java
@Test
public void operationIsCalledWithSpecificState() {
    StatefulOperation operation = mock(StatefulOperation.class);
    StatefulService statefulService = new StatefulService(operation);

    doAnswer(answerVoid((Stateful s) -> assertEquals("Input", s.getValue())))
            .when(operation).doOperation(any());

    statefulService.execute(new Stateful("Input"));
    Mockito.verify(operation).doOperation(any());
}
```